# How to hide a class inside another class ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to hide a class inside another class?

```
class A
  class B; end
end
```

I want class B to be invisible outside class A

What should I do for this

```
b = A::B.new
```

to be an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define your inner class like this:

```
class A
  class B
    # ...
  end
  private_constant :B

  # ...
end
```

That would allow the use from inside the  class. But when you try `A::B.new` an error is thrown:

```
A::B.new
# NameError: private constant A::B referenced
```

You might want to read more about this in this [blog post](https://blog.arkency.com/2016/02/private-classes-in-ruby/).

Comment: You mean it would allow the use from inside the class.